# ScrollView кривая прокрутка при появление клавиатуры

Tags: android, xml

Некорректно работает скролл при появление клавиатуры. внизу появляется дополнительное пустое место а верх обрезается и до него невозможно доскролиться. Как это решить? 
в манифесте стоит:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/c3"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LoginActivity">

<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="71dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:alpha="0.9"
        android:background="@drawable/oval_corner"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            android:text="ToggleButton"
            android:textOff="@string/toggle_button_off"
            android:textOn="@string/toggle_button_on" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:imeActionId="6"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_first_name"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/second_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_second_name"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/lastname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_last_name"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/layout_search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_group"
                    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/register"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: pic]
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема решилась добавлением в scrollview

```
 android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
 android:fillViewport="true"
```